# Eclipse (ADT) selectively not finding/showing SOME hpp files

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am trying to set up an environment to work with Eclipse ADT, NDK/JNI, Open CV, and COCOS2d-X (fun, fun, don't ask ;-)

I managed to do some simple example and also it seems the cocos2d-x dependencies are resolved correctly (I setup the project with cocos project builder script and trying to work with open CV from within it. On Visual Studio I had the project running without any issues).

Now when I try to compile the source of a project (proj.android) I am seeing the files

```
In file included from jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:2:0:
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.h:8:30: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Now I've set the include path (Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths And Symbols -> Includes (tab).
I've tried to set a path relative to the project and also an absolution path. I tried with both back and forward slashes and I tried to include the path to either opencv\build\include and also to the android for open CV specific path (\opencv\OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include)

What is odd is that in the IDE I see the directory strcutrue within the include directory (e.g. opencv2/core etc) and also some of the files in the directory - but some header files are not found be the IDE (and obviously, by the compiler).

I have the opencv examples and I manage to compile them - also the IDE sees all the include files and does not emit any of them. I tried to copy the settings from that project (tutorial 2 - mixed processing) but it didn't help. The only difference that I see between them (other than location) is that the cocos2dx project uses build_native.sh (and rely on cygwin) while the open cv samples uses ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd to build.

For example see the attached images:

IDE:
[image: IDE not showing all header files]

Project Settings:
[image: Project Properties]

The file system:
[image: Files in the include directory]

The same happens with many header files - the IDE only showing me some (the ones I don't need)

I am not that familiar with make files and the whole build process nor do I have *nix experience and this is really frustrating - wasting so much time on something that should be trivial (if not the build, at least for the IDE to show the files).

Below is full output of the build:

```
01:09:44 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project MyBox2d ****
bash D:/cocos2d-x-2.2.3/projects/MyBox2d/proj.android/build_native.sh 
NDK_ROOT = D:\android-ndk-r9c
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/cocos2d-x-2.2.3/projects/MyBox2d/proj.android/../../..
APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/cocos2d-x-2.2.3/projects/MyBox2d/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/d/cocos2d-x-2.2.3/projects/MyBox2d/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
make: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/cocos2d-x-2.2.3/projects/MyBox2d/proj.android'
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:cocos2dcpp_shared: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/d/cocos2d-x-    2.2.3/projects/MyBox2d/proj.android/../../../cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= main.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= AppDelegate.cpp
In file included from jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:2:0:
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.h:7:30: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/d/android-ndk-r9c/build/core/build-binary.mk:388: recipe for targett 'obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/cocos2d-x-2.2.3/projects/MyBox2d/proj.android'
```

Comment: Did you added all opencv related files in your `Android.mk` file?

Comment: Hi Valdimir - I have not - as I wrote, no familiar with Make and didn't find any specific article to show how to do it. In addition, if does not recognize some of the files in the IDE - does this also can be related to make file contents?